# How to detect the trained images in the neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have used Convolutional Neural Network(CNN) to train the legends in the maps. These legends are circles, ovals, diamonds, crosses, and squares. The neural network (inspired from the code https://towardsdatascience.com/from-raw-images-to-real-time-predictions-with-deep-learning-ddbbda1be0e4) works well in my case. The input images are individual cropped pictures of legends like [input trained image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVOMq.png) and the output I want is to predict these legends in the maps like [input maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56OKo.png). My neural network can now classify the images and predict whether they are squares or circles. For example, when I provided this image [diamondinput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8Vdk.png) as input, the output is diamond.

```
from keras.models import model_from_json
import numpy as np

EMOTIONS_LIST = ["circle","cross","diamond","oval","square"]
def predict_emotion(img):
        preds = model.predict(img)
        return EMOTIONS_LIST[np.argmax(preds)]
import cv2
import numpy as np
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import keras
#model =  keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/model_weights_updated.h5')
fr=cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/Images/train/diamond/Copy of 0076.tif')
gray_fr = cv2.cvtColor(fr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
roi = cv2.resize(gray_fr, (48, 48))
pred = predict_emotion(roi[np.newaxis, :, :, np.newaxis])
print(pred)
```

**Output for the program:**

> [[1.7809551e-06 2.4862277e-07 9.9999583e-01 2.1272169e-06 8.9550163e-09]], diamond

How can I make the neural network to predict these legends in the map and all other legends in the map like this [outputmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76NgC.png)?.

Comment: just to clarify: you want to detect the circles on the map?

Comment: Yes, not only circles, there are sometimes squares or diamonds too and I want to detect all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the network you got, it would be possible to just split each map into a grid and then perform classification for each segment in the grid, but there are many problems with such an approach.

A better solution for you would be to use a neural network that does semantic segmentation. This way, your network regresses a likelihood-map for each of your shapes on the map. With this likelihood-map, you will know how many you have of each class and where they are.

To do so, you can start with the following MaskRCNN implementation.

https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN

Comment: Thank you very much:)

Comment: Please get familiar with the site [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). A user cannot vote up until they reach 15 rep points.